# redirect only works if original folder exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I imported some 1000 files into wordpress and created htaccess redirects like this:

`Redirect 301 /folder_a/name.htm    http://www.example.com/folder_b/folder_a/name/`

This worked fine until I renamed the original folder to folder_a_old. No more redirects. Instead I got "File not found". The old page would not show (of course), but the new Wordpress page would also not show.  When I restored the name of the original folder redirects worked again. What is the explanation for this behavior and how can I remove the original folder (to avoid mix-up)?

Comment: please give more information like the new redirect code and the old one

Comment: I stated the redirect code I'm using.
The old file was: "http://www.example.com/folder_a/name.htm"
the wordpress page is: "http://www.example.com/folder_b/folder_a/name/"

Comment: you renamed this folder_a  with folder_a_old ?

Comment: Yes. And after renaming the redirect didn't work anymore.

Comment: ok , do you only want to redirect name.htm only to that directory?

Comment: No, I have 1600 redirects.

Comment: i will reply wait

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Redirect 301 /folder_a/    http://www.example.com/folder_b/folder_a/name/
```

The code above will redirect every request to `folder_a` to `http://www.example.com/folder_b/folder_a/name/` for example :

```
yoursite/folder_a/test.php   to http://www.example.com/folder_b/folder_a/name/test.php
```

**Note:** clear browser cache the test it.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not answering my question.